# How to use required fields when using react-hook-form with yupResolver and Typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, yup

The following type is auto-generated from the OpenAPI specs of the Rest API, therefore I can't simply change it:

```js
export type InventoryItemCreate = {
  name: string;
  status_id: number;
  barcode?: string;
  //...
};
```

Based on this, I'm trying to define a react-hook-form with Yup for validation as follows:

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required('Name ist ein Pflichtfeld'),
  barcode: Yup.string()
    .min(5, 'Der Barcode muss 5-stellig sein')
    .max(5, 'Der Barcode muss 5-stellig sein')
    .matches(/^[A-Z][0-9]{4}$/, 'Muss das Format X0000 haben')
    .optional()
    .nullable(),
  rfid_id: Yup.string().optional().nullable(),
  description: Yup.string().nullable(),
  wiki_url: Yup.string().optional().nullable(),
  other_owner: Yup.string().optional().nullable(),
  model: Yup.string().optional().nullable(),
  vendor: Yup.string().optional().nullable()
});
```

This is then used as follows:

```
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

export const InventoryItemForm = ({ existingItem }: { existingItem?: InventoryItem }) => {
  
  // omitted

  const formContext = useForm<InventoryItemFormSchema>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    values: existingItem
  });
```

This however results in the following error message:

```
./components/inventory/InventoryItemForm.tsx:67:5
Type error: Type 'Resolver<{ name?: string; barcode?: string; description?: string; rfid_id?: string; wiki_url?: string; other_owner?: string; model?: string; vendor?: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<InventoryItemFormSchema, any>'.
  Types of parameters 'options' and 'options' are incompatible.
    Type 'ResolverOptions<InventoryItemFormSchema>' is not assignable to type 'ResolverOptions<{ name?: string; barcode?: string; description?: string; rfid_id?: string; wiki_url?: string; other_owner?: string; model?: string; vendor?: string; }>'.
      Types of property 'names' are incompatible.
        Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'OptionalKeys<{ name: string; barcode: string; rfid_id: string; description: string; wiki_url: string; other_owner: string; model: string; vendor: string; }>[]'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'OptionalKeys<{ name: string; barcode: string; rfid_id: string; description: string; wiki_url: string; other_owner: string; model: string; vendor: string; }>'.

  65 | 
  66 |   const formContext = useForm<InventoryItemFormSchema>({
> 67 |     resolver: yupResolver(schema),
     |     ^
  68 |     values: existingItem
  69 |   });
  70 | 
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

If I manually change the Type definition and make name optional, then the error goes away. That being said, the `name` attribute is required in the Yup schema, is there any way to make sure the returned value has this as non-optional type?

```js
export type InventoryItemCreate = {
  name?: string;  // <= This change makes it work
  status_id: number;
  barcode?: string;
  //...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly pass the generic type if you have a validation schema. The type is derived from the schema.

Comment: nice one @moshyfawn, removing the type from the useForm call fixed the problem. R